# How to parallelise Spark to Kafka writes

Tags: apache-spark

The Kafka producer returns a Java Future (or you can use the callback) anyway, in my spark job I want to make sure that things are correctly sent and that it goes fast.

Using:

```
rdd.foreach { msg =>
 kafkaProducer.send(msg).get() //wait for the future to complete
}
```

does not perform well at all.

I was thinking of using

```
rdd.repartition(20).foreachPartition { iterator =>
 iterator.foreach { msg =>
 kafkaProducer.send(msg).get()
 }
}
```

my question is though, is foreachPartition going to run in parallel? It's hard to see from a simple test I've written as it appears that the content of foreachPartition are run from the same thread. But I don't know if this depends on my test setup...

Comment: Refer this link https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/streaming-kafka-0-8-integration.html

Comment: that is about spark streaming does it apply?

Comment: from spark stream, you can get rdd depending on time interval set while creating  the streaming context